# Log4J logger without appender use

Tags: java, logging, log4j

If I have a log4j.xml file that I'm using to init the loggers, with a logger(`foo`) defined in it without any `appender-ref` tags within it, what does this logger do? If it does nothing, does it have an impact on performance?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"> 
    <param name="Target" value="System.out"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"> 
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %c{1} - %m%n"/> 
    </layout> 
  </appender> 

  <logger name="foo">
    <level value="WARN"/>
  </logger>

  <root> 
    <priority value ="debug" /> 
    <appender-ref ref="console" /> 
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logger is adding warning logs and they are generated whenever there is a warning in console program for which this logger config is running, it will add it to logs and yes it will have impacts on performance as we are adding logs only for debug. If you see in xml, priority value is set to debug
if it is set to Release then it will log the release mode messages
The impact will be huge as we should log errors as well. That is the whole purpose of logger..

Comment: But I've not added an appender to this logger. Would this logger also still put the logs on the console?

Comment: @ayushgp No it should not put,you need to put the same logger in your code.If you have further doubts please don't hesitate to clarify and if you think I have answered your question correct then it accept my answer and please upvote it.Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

From the manual: "Each enabled logging request for a given logger will be forwarded to all the appenders in that logger as well as the appenders higher in the hierarchy" So I guess they will inherit from root.